# handle:connection():ssl():subjectPeerCertificate() returns "" after upgrading to Istio 1.10.6, indicating no peer certificate found

Tags: ssl, istio, envoyproxy

We're using Lua filter in EnvoyFilter in Istio to check certificate details.
The usage looks like below (the detailed verification to the client_cert_name is omitted).

```
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/version_history/v1.14.0#deprecated
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
        proxy:
          proxyVersion: ^1\.10.*
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/lua/v3/lua.proto#extension-envoy-filters-http-lua
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(handle)
                -- https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#subjectpeercertificate
                local client_cert_name = handle:connection():ssl():subjectPeerCertificate()
                if client_cert_name == "" and handle:headers():get("Authorization") == nil then
                  handle:respond({[":status"] = "401"},"Unauthorized")
                end
```

The function `handle:connection():ssl():subjectPeerCertificate()` worked well in Istio 1.9.9, however, after upgrading to 1.10.6, without other changes, no peer certificate is found, and the function just returns empty.
We've checked the documents of Istio and Envoy for long time, but find no breaking change for this function. A couple of attempts such as adding the LISTENER MERGE patch like [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21059#issuecomment-592244520) doesn't help.
Could you help suggest where could be the problem?

Comment: Could you update your istio to the newest version?

Comment: It's said no recommended to upgrade Istio over multiple versions in one time, so we just upgraded Istio from 1.9.x to 1.10.x. I tried upgrading again to 1.11.5 but no luck. I could have another try to 1.12 while I'm not sure if it won't introduce other issues. Let me get back for more updates.

Comment: Ok, please share your update, when you have it :)

Comment: 1.12 still has the same issue. Rollback to 1.9 resolves the problem. Still need to investigate the root cause. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it turned out that from Istio 1.10, there's a [commit](https://github.com/istio/istio/commit/f89a49dcb951b318e6bafb0bbe91c4c4f068b057) which makes Istio do not add validation context for SIMPLE. Until the latest version, 1.12.1, the logic is still there.

Our service use SIMPLE as the TLS mode in the gateway, which causes the problem described in this question, as shown below:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
... 
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
```

After changing the mode to MUTUAL, the problem is resolved.